# Proper Android Thread Use, Set-Up, and Purpose

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm new to android programming and have a somewhat limited base of knowledge of java. I am working on a relatively simple android app. It only uses two activity pages and a view page. I am almost done with the program; however I am not using any threads. I just use buttons to call activities and then include other buttons to "re-open" the main activity page. My question is do I particularly need threads with a simple program like I have. And if so, what is the purpose of using them and what would the basic structure be? (For example, how are threads properly set up? Do I use one main thread to call other threads?) Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't performing any long running tasks (some examples are network, file, or database interaction), then you likely do not need any threads. There are many good tutorials and explanations of threading for Java around the Internet that you can take advantage of if you wish to learn more.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am not going to perform any long-running tasks; however how would I take into account a possible interruption? For example, the user getting a text, or clicking the "home" button for the main android screen? I understand that when using threads, this is accomplished via onPause()/onResume().

Comment: That's not accomplish via any threading methods you need to be concerned with. You can perform tasks in onPause / onResume if you wish (and they will get triggered on some of the events you mentioned) but it has nothing to do with threads in the way you mentioned.